# Why on third expose-event event.area is smaller then before?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

See yourself:

```
import gtk

def expose(widget, event):
        print event.area

win = gtk.Window()
win.show()
win.connect('expose-event', expose)  
gtk.main()
```

so,the result is:

```
gtk.gdk.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200)
gtk.gdk.Rectangle(0, 0, 200, 200)
gtk.gdk.Rectangle(194, 0, 6, 200)
```

and there are no scroll-bars...
Why that happens and how to avoid of this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is probably system & library dependent.  On LMDE, using stock python, I only get the first two exposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As ergosys said - "This is probably system & library dependent. On LMDE, using stock python, I only get the first two exposes.". I checked LMDE and he is right.